How to create table with identity column using entity framework core code first migration to oracle db?
This is the code generated by ef core after we do add-migration
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
     name: "Provinces",
     ////schema: "some schema",
     columns: table => new
     {
         Id = table.Column<int>(type: "NUMBER(10)", nullable: false)
             .Annotation("Oracle:Identity", "START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1"),
         Title = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(255)", maxLength: 255, nullable: false),
         Code = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(10)", maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
         Deleted = table.Column<bool>(type: "NUMBER(1)", nullable: false)
     },
     constraints: table =>
     {
         table.PrimaryKey("PK_Provinces", x => x.Id);
     });

I expected it to work against oracle db 11
but its saying error msg like: missing always keyword for identity column creation
Edit
Instead of doing it manually i solved it with SQLCompatibility Version Set in DBConfigure


I expected it to work against oracle db 11

Oracle 11g does not support IDENTITY columns; they were introduced in Oracle 12.
If you are using Oracle 11g then you will need to use a trigger and a sequence to manage the identity.

so seems i need to add them manually to all tables... and ef auto migration script is not working... is that?

the actual solution was to add target compatibility version in dbconfigure or dbcontext creation
